# Goto Function in Embedded Strings

Tags: string, while-loop, goto

So I'm Trying To goto function in one of my switches(inside Second Switch). But it is doing Nothing (it worked fine in first switch). Any logical errors here?

login_page:

```
while (....)
{
    ...
    switch (...)
    {
        ...
    case(2): 
        {
            ...
                switch (...) 
                {
                    ...
                case(1):
                    {
                        goto login_page;
                        break;
                    }
                    ...
                }
            ....
        }
        ....
    }
    ...
   }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take [the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Can you add a tag indicating which programming language you are using?